# Bullets on data in table makes it to loose alignment (takes it to top)

Tags: html, css

On my page:

XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX

I have a table that has bullets in first column data, when I put bullets the first column, the columns losses its alignment, it takes it on top relative to next columns. But when I remove bullets, the table shows fine.

I don't have problem with indent, I have issue with data going on top  of table.

Please note: I have no padding (0 value) and margin on any row or column or data.

See table 1 and table 2 in the page: XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX

Table 2 is what I want, but with bullets.

I am using bullets as:

```
<ul>
  <li>XXXXXXXXXXXX</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add this to your CSS styles:

```
ul, ol {
  margin: 0 0 0 3em;
}
```

Comment: ok, it worked. thanks, but what is the reason that it causes trouble with bullets?

Comment: it was originally set to `margin: 0 0 1.5em 3em;` giving it an unwanted high associated with the bullet.

Comment: ok. thanks. I did not set it, I am using a wordpress plugin to add table in Elementor. may be that is adding padding / margin.

Comment: Probably added by the theme then. this should override it.